# Why Prism's Master Detail Page structure is different from Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I developed one app about months ago with Prism. It's great tool that make perfect structure for my app.
However, today I tried to pick up that app and fix some things that pending for a long time. I used Master Detail page in my app, and today I suddenly found that actually the structure for how I developed this Master Detail page using Prism is kind of out of my knowledge.

So, here it is.

Basically my MasterDetailPage is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="JapaneseLearnPrism.Views.MenuPage">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <NavigationPage Title="Menu" Icon="ic_hamburger.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <ContentPage Title="{Binding Title}">
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              SeparatorColor="LightGray"
                              RowHeight="60"
                              SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                              BackgroundColor="#e8e8e8">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                 Padding="20,10,0,10"
                                                 Spacing="20">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding PageIconText}" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListView.Behaviors>
                            <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" />
                        </ListView.Behaviors>
                    </ListView>
                </ContentPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

And the navigation path is this in App.xaml.cs file.

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(MenuPage) + "/" + nameof(NavigationPage) + "/" + nameof(Views.MainPage));
```

But if I look at lots of the Xamarin.Forms samples, the MasterDetailPage is actually different.
They are going to do like below:

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetailPageNavigation;assembly=MasterDetailPageNavigation"
                  x:Class="MasterDetailPageNavigation.MainPage">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:ContactsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

And that's from Microsoft's official website. The Master Page in above is actually just one ContentPage, however, the Detail page should be NavigationPage, that one I can understand because it makes sense.

However, in my Prism app, the MasterPage also has to be a NavigaionPage, why is that? Any one can help on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this wonderfull blog about [How to make Master-Detail Page Navigation menu in Xamarin Forms with Prism](https://almirvuk.blogspot.com/2018/03/how-to-make-master-detail-page.html).
If you scroll down to the bottom of the post, you will see some description on why it works this way, Quoting:

> Note: Navigation in Prism is all based on this url format where we can define to which pages we want to go, and it can be something like this: ViewA/ViewB/ViewC/ViewD

---

> ... and if you remember we are inside of MasterDetail page so navigating from MasterDetail will get result that those pages will go to Detail part of it... and that is great for us, we have menu in side of master page and choosing menu items will open pages as Detail pages.

The way that Prism Navigation is designed, it makes sense that a DetaiPage goes inside the MasterDetail, so basically it keeps the Prism Logic of doing the Navigation.

---

Quoting the Basics of [Prism Navigation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/navigation-basics.html)

> Navigating in a Prism application is conceptually different than standard navigation in Xamarin.Forms. While Xamarin.Forms navigation relies on a Page class instance to navigate, Prism removes all dependencies on Page types to achieve loosely coupled navigation from within a ViewModel. In Prism, the concept of navigating to a View or navigating to a ViewModel does not exist. Instead, you simply navigate to an experience, or a unique identifier, which represents the target view you wish to navigate to in your application.

Comment: That is so cool. Even the quotes make so much sense!
Thanks, and I am marking this as answer! But I do have another issue that i am going to post, should I ask here?

Comment: @AllenLiu-MSFT i'm glad that i manage to put the information in a way that was comprehensive for you

Comment: Yeah, that was great. I will post another question and 90 minutes since it's the limitation for SO. Maybe you can also take a look at that problem that I got as well.

Comment: @AllenLiu-MSFT if i know the solution i will glady anwser it

Comment: Cool. Actually I think I can type here first. Basically is this line of code: `<NavigationPage Title="Menu" Icon="ic_hamburger.png">` in the Master Page that works fine on my Android device to show the hamburger icon, but not on iOS. I am not sure why. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I posted the question also there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60228891/hamburger-icon-not-showing-on-ios-developed-by-prism-for-xamarin-forms
You can also reply to there is you have the answer. :)

Comment: @AllenLiu-MSFT i would prefer if you wait and ask it in a Question format, since SO guidelines indicate that you shouldn't ask diferent questions in the same one, this includes comments on the question/anwsers