# Hamburger icon not showing on iOS developed by Prism for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, prism

Below is my XAML page for my MasterDetailPage:

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="JapaneseLearnPrism.Views.MenuPage">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <NavigationPage Title="Menu" Icon="ic_hamburger.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <ContentPage Title="{Binding Title}">
                    <!--Content for my menus here.-->
                </ContentPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

And this is how I set up the Page Path for Prism:

```cs
protected override async void OnInitialized()
{
    InitializeComponent();
            Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.Application.SetWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(this, Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);

    // await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(MenuPage) + "/" + nameof(NavigationPage) + "/" + nameof(Views.MainPage));
}
```

This is works fine for the MD page function. And the hamburger icon is correctly showing in Android but not iOS. I am wondering why. I searched online everyone but actually nothing solved.
Hope be able to get the answer here.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried removing             <x:Arguments>
                <ContentPage Title="{Binding Title}">
                    <!--Content for my menus here.-->
                </ContentPage>
            </x:Arguments> ??, because you can't have content in your NavigationPage

Comment: I am sorry you want me to remove all the ContentPage content from NavigationPage? So you mean just an empty NavigationPage tag?

Comment: just took a closer look and it's correct, did some reasearch and it's like you said, it seems like an unresolved issue from XF, not Prism https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1394

Comment: https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/42/42548/bug.html this bugzilla seems to be the one with most discussion on the subject

Comment: I think this might be able to be done by a custom renderer. Let me have a try maybe.

Comment: yes, this issue seems to be forgotten, sadly, i can't come up with a solution to this, maybe someone has an anwser

Comment: Use ` IconImageSource="ic_hamburger.png" ` inside MasterDetailPage Tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IconImageSource inside MasterDetailPage to display HamburgerIcon as far as Android is concern it uses it's default hamburger Icon that's why it is showing in Android and not in iOS.

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             IconImageSource="ic_hamburger.png"
             x:Class="JapaneseLearnPrism.Views.MenuPage">
```

Comment: That's correct, but I used assets to save images so that it looks much better with only one picture.